# Idhttp pegar tamanho do arquivo baixado

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Bom, gostaria de saber como descubro o tamanho do arquivo que está sendo baixando com o componente IdHttp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem de solicitar a operação HEAD com o endereço do arquivo

```
var
  HttpClient: TIdHttp;
  FileSize: Int64;
begin
  HttpClient := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
  try
    HttpClient.Head('http://somewhere.com/somefile.exe');
    FileSize := HttpClient.Response.ContentLength;
  finally
    HttpClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```